# Visual Studio Code - Find webpack alias with export all

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, babeljs

In our code base, we have a couple exports defined as // for an alias as the src directory. In the sub-folders of our src directory we are doing imports for sub-files via something like this:

```
- src
  - one
    - two.js
    - three.js
    - index.js
```

In two.js we are exporting a bunch of functions, we'll call one **run**. In index.js we are doing

`export * from ./two`

So in our main file we can import like this

```
import { run } from '//one';
```

The problem is when i'm trying to find the declaration it points me to the import statement instead of the function declaration.

I have tried adding the following to my root directory but this was still not able to find the declaration. Does anybody have any ideas what I can try or am I just out of luck due to how we're exporting and importing functions. I tried looking [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig) but couldn't figure it out

jsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "es2017",
      "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": false,
      "baseUrl": "./",
      "paths": {
        "//*": ["src/*"]
      }
    },
    "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist"]
}
```

Other notes: We are using Babel compiler to compile ES2017 with a reactjs project.